# Maximize apps on second screen only maximizes to half the width

Tags: release-loki, display, window-management

I'm running Elementary OS Loki on the newest Dell XPS 13. Been trying to setup a dual extended screen but I recently noticed that whenever I maximize an application on this screen it will maximize to only half of the width as the image shows:
[image: dual screen image]

This is the output for `xrandr --current` (not sure if relevant but might as well add it):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 2880, maximum 32767 x 32767 eDP1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
    3200x1800     59.98*+  47.99  
    2880x1620     60.00  
    2560x1440     60.00  
    2048x1536     60.00  
    1920x1440     60.00  
    1856x1392     60.01  
    1792x1344     60.01  
    2048x1152     60.00  
    1920x1200     59.95  
    1920x1080     60.00    59.93  
    1600x1200     60.00  
    1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
    1600x1024     60.17  
    1400x1050     59.98  
    1600x900      60.00  
    1280x1024     60.02  
    1440x900      59.89  
    1280x960      60.00  
    1368x768      60.00  
    1360x768      59.80    59.96  
    1152x864      60.00  
    1280x720      60.00  
    1024x768      60.00  
    1024x576      60.00  
    960x540       60.00  
    800x600       60.32    56.25  
    864x486       60.00  
    640x480       59.94  
    720x405       60.00  
    640x360       60.00  
DP1 connected 1920x1080+625+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
    1920x1080     60.00*+
    1600x900      60.00  
    1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
    1152x864      75.00  
    1024x768      75.08    60.00  
    800x600       75.00    60.32  
    640x480       75.00    60.00  
    720x400       70.08
```

Comment: How do you maximize the application?

Comment: @lemonslice using the shortcut on the upper right window corner.

Comment: Actually it is more like a bug report, however I cannot even confirm it…

Comment: @lemonslice I'm happy to file a bug report if you feel that's the case. Just wanted to confirm everything before doing it.